# Browser is buffering the response and displaying it all together although it is supposed to be in chunks

Tags: php, javascript, stream, buffer, flush

I want to have some data flow from the server in an infinite loop. At server side, php flushes the output at a frequency but I have to set every chunk of data in some certain size (1KB for instance).

I figure that this is caused by the browser buffering the response. So I want to try to manipulate browser's this behavior via javascript.

Comment: Some browser only cache the first few hundred kb, after that they do chunk it like expected. You can easily test that by invoking `readyState 3` from an `XHR` object.

Comment: Have you tried getting the chunks via individual Ajax requests?

Comment: There's some information on buffering and various browsers in the PHP Manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php but I seriously doubt you can manipulate the browser behaviour in this manner with JavaScript

Comment: @Nev Stokes thanks for the link i had actually checked the page but i think i should have checked more carefuly :) There is one note that looks very useful that I didn't notice before.

By the way my actual intention is not to use multiple requests in order to save time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to accept that the browser buffers the response and pad the chunks to the buffer size using white space anything of your choice.

You will have to know how much each browser buffers to decide the padding bytes. This can be done by doing tests for each browser and after that checking user agent information on the server side.

Another approach is of course using websockets instead